# Unable to add items to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a `dialog` where I need to add name and If I click `Ok` button that name entered in the `edittext` should be added to my `ListView` which is in `fragment`

This is my homefragment:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
```

Here is my input-dialog:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter name for shopping list" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/list_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

This is my fragment_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <ListView android:id="@+id/itemslistView"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="75dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my dialog code:

```
protected void showInputDialog() {

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
            .findViewById(R.id.list_text);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater
                            .from(MainActivity.this);
                    View lstview = layoutInflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.fragment_home, null);
                    lv = (ListView) lstview
                            .findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
                    List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String NewListname=editText.getText().toString();
                    MyList.add(NewListname);
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list, MyList);
                    lv.setAdapter(adp);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

This is my HomeFragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);


        return rootView;

    }
}
```

My problem is I'm able to get the text from edittext as shown with toast but unable to add it to listview.

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong?

Comment: :Pls post your HomeFragment code here.

Comment: @Deepak Singh-Updated code. Please check.

Comment: [check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221758/update-listview-after-post-new-data-from-dialogfragment/27222072#27222072). call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after lv.setAdapter(adp);

Comment: are you getting any error ??? you are not even able to toast the text so debug the code

Comment: @SweetWisherツ- I'm able to get the toast but unable to add it to list view and I'm not getting any exceptions. I think my problem is with listview

Comment: @coder Still didn't get solution?

Comment: @Piyush- No I'm unable to get it working yet

Answer (score 1):

After adding text in your `MyList` you just called   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

No need to  `setAdapter(adp);` again

Comment: @coder No you are doing something wrong. i thought.

Comment: @M D-I have added the entire xml part too..I dont understand where am I going wrong with this. I think this is unable to get the listview I hope so.

Comment: @coder You're right. Your `ListView` coming from `fragment_home` and you've implement in your `Dialog`. that's wrong.

Comment: so how do I modify that ?

Comment: @coder I already suggest you go with `Dialog Fragment` and create some `Listener` that can set string from `Dialog Fragment` to your `Fragment` and get this string in your `Fragment` and then add it to your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

*Please try with follwing code (i never tried in devices)*

```
protected void showInputDialog() {

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
            .findViewById(R.id.list_text);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View lstview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    lv = (ListView) lstview.findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
    List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list, MyList);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    String NewListname = editText.getText().toString();
                    MyList.add(NewListname);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Eventhough I modified as what you said it dosent show anything

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In your HomeFragment:

```
List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
```

protected void showInputDialog() 
{

```
// get prompts.xml view
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
        .findViewById(R.id.list_text);
// setup a dialog window
alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                String NewListname=editText.getText().toString();
                MyList.add(NewListname);
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        MainActivity.this, R.layout.list, MyList);
                lv.setAdapter(adp);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

// create an alert dialog
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
```

}

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it replaces the same list but I want to add to the existing one. For example.. If I have added "Apple" and next time If I add "Orange" it replaces Apple. But I want to add beaneath Apple

Comment: @coder: Add this line  adp.notifyDataSetChanged(); after lv.setAdapter(adp);